# Does the character encoding of functions like fopen() depends on the locale of the process that invoked them?

Tags: c, linux

When you use a function like `fopen()`, you have to pass it a string argument for the filename. Does the character encoding of this string depend on the locale of the process that invoked the function?

If it does, then on which locale category does the character encoding depend?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005570/what-encoding-used-when-invoke-fopen-or-open

Answer (score 0):

You have this tagged `linux` so...

It depends on how you mount the file system, just take a look at mount options for different file systems in `man mount`. For example `iso9660`, `vfat` and `fat` have `iocharset` and `utf8` options.

Beyond this it's simply a "NUL-terminated, '/'-delimited sequence of bytes"